# Drop Schema and Exclude Indexes/constraints

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to drop a schema in Dev env but not Indexes and Constraints.
And while taking the export(dump) from Production also exclude both these.
So that it can save my time to update the schema from production to dev env.
Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean that you want to truncate all the tables in the schema?

Comment: As nop wrote below. If we drop schema then everything will be dropped. Drop Schema execute in some seconds. If i go for truncate all the tables then i think it will take more time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as you drop a schema in Oracle, you drop everything the schema contains, including indexes and constraints owned by that schema or pointing to that schema.